# Button under the other HTML <ul>

Tags: html

Here is my code :

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <small style="margin-left:2px;">John: </small>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <small style="margin-left:2px;">Eva: </small>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">B</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <small style="margin-left:2px;">Michael: </small>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">A</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <small style="margin-left:2px;">Error: </small>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <small style="margin-left:2px;">ASD: </small>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to show the buttons one under the other, like when I style the buttons with `margin-left`, but I can't do it with every button, because in original code there are many more.

So is there a solution for `<ul><li></li></ul>` ?

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/eeLuK6Fa60JEco2LVTKO?p=preview

Comment: I think you'll need a container `div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy approach is to find the widest word and use it's width as a fixed width for all `<small>`

```css
small{
  width:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li><small>John: </small><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
  <li><small>Eva: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">B</button></li>
  <li><small>Michael: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">A</button></li>
  <li><small>Error: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
  <li><small>ASD: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below CSS with position relative for li and positin absolute to button

```
small{
  margin-left:2px;
  }

li{
  position:relative
}

li button{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QrOBXW

```css
small{
  margin-left:2px;
  }

li{
  position:relative
}

li button{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="toaster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="toaster.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
      asd
    
       <ul>
          <li><small>John: </small> <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
       <li><small>Eva: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">B</button></li>
       <li><small>Michael: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">A</button></li>
       <li><small>Error: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
       <li><small>ASD: </small><button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button></li>
      
                        </ul>
                        

        
    </body>
```

**Option 2:**

Set li width and make buttons float right to the li element

CSS:

```
small{
  margin-left:2px;
  }

li{
  width:100px;
  padding:5px;
}

li button{
  float:right
}
```

code smaple - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qYVMOo

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a class to the `<ul>` or `<li>` where you want to add the style.

Comment: what class? Have you any idea?

Comment: @bafix2203, any class. you define how it affects the list